# How to install updates during system shutdown?

Tags: systemd, reboot

This question applies to RedHat 7,8,9 (and derivatives), as well as Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 (all of them systemd-based). My guess is that the answer will be the similar for all, but I found that they are not the same.

I would like to "hook" into the system shutdown sequence in order to install updates. The idea being that, since maintenance windows for reboot are hard to obtain, and admins sometimes forget to install updates before rebooting, I want this to happen automatically.

I also want this to happen regardless of how or why the shutdown was initiated, whether with shutdown -r, shutdown -h, systemctl reboot, or any of the various other methods.

The general outline of hooking into the shutdown sequence with systemd is easy enough:

```
# This service is will watch for a clean shutdown, and install updates etc.
# before the actual shutdown.

# Credit goes to https://opensource.com/life/16/11/running-commands-shutdown-linux

[Unit]
Description=Run package updates at shutdown
#------------ Ubuntu version ------------
Requires=network.target
BindsTo=network.target multi-user.target systemd-resolved.service rsyslog.service
After=network.target multi-user.target systemd-resolved.service rsyslog.service
#------------ RedHat version ------------
Requires=network.target
BindsTo=network.target multi-user.target boot.mount rsyslog.service
After=network.target multi-user.target boot.mount rsyslog.service
#------------- End distro specific ---------
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=update_script.sh
# Allow enough time to complete an update. Default would be 90 seconds
TimeoutStopSec=3600

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

update_script.sh does this:

```
systemstatus=$(systemctl is-system-running)
case "$systemstatus" in
 stopping)
   <do updates>
   ;;
 *)
   # Unknown state, don't do updates
   # This prevents updates when starting/stopping the service manually.
   ;;
esac
```

The problem here is that the updates happen when the process is already partially shut down. As a result, some updates would not properly install.

But when I put the script too early in the shutdown sequence, systemctl is-system-running reports "running" instead of "shutting down" - in that case, the script believes that the service was just stopped manually, and does not perform the updates.

What I need is:

- A way to run this service first, before any other part of the shutdown sequence.
- A way to prevent systemd from concurrently shutting down any other services.
- A way to reliably detect even during the early stages that the system is in the process of shutting down, before "systemd is-system-running" reports it correctly.

Or alternatively, I need some other (clean, non-hackish) way to hook into the system shutdown before anything else is shut down.

Note: I have also experimented with doing the updates in the startup phase instead of the shutdown phase. But this might necessitate a second reboot, so it is not desirable.

Comment: The only Linux component which can't be updated at runtime is the kernel (that's actually possible but requires a special kernel). No idea why you simply can't update.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov There actually are a few other components, such as dbus and systemd. More accurately, you can update these components just fine at runtime, but the updates won't become active until the next reboot. And you can get inconsistent system states eventually. But that's not the problem I'm facing here. I want to install updates *immediately before* the system is shutting down, and can't seem to get this to work.

Comment: systemd can perfectly be updated at runtime. No idea where you got this information from. I'm not entirely sure about dbus but I presume it can be updated as well.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov some parts of systemd can be updated as they run as ordinary processes, but at least one part that as far as I know can't be updated is the PID 1 process (or the binaries running in it). I think there are a number of other essential parts of systemd that require a reboot.

Comment: systemd PID 1 and all its "dependent" processes **can** be restarted. This feature was implemented years ago.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thank you for all your information! If you don't mind me asking a follow-up question. I have a RedHat system (RHEL 9) where the tracer utility reports it needs to be rebooted. because systemd has been updated. The kernel has not changed. This message stays even after I restart PID 1 with systemctl daemon-reexec. Do you know the proper way to restart systemd without a reboot?

Comment: Please ask a new question about this tracer stuff specifically. I've never dealt with it so I don't know.